# Jxbrowser 6.20: Search in Large size Pdf(approx in GB's) is throwing exception com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException

Tags: java, jxbrowser

Jxbrowser : I was searching for the text in large size pdf( approx in Gb's) opened in Jxbrowser .I clicked enter, then jxbrowser thread hangs for 120 seconds and the problem is only reproducible while doing the search in Pdf.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Response was not received.
2018-09-25 21:48:59,039 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR com.pg.orion.eng.startUp.StandardStream -  at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.findText(SourceFile:1248)

When search happens till then show some progress Bar for user point of View.

Can anybody tell me is this known issue ? And, any planning to resolve the issue in upcoming JxBrowser Releases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to call Browser.findText() in EDT as text finding might take some time depending on the PDF document size.

If you call this method in EDT you will block UI for a while and an exception might be thrown in large sized PDF files.

Please try calling this method in a different thread.